# Application design using HTTP and HTTPS together

Tags: security

I need to build a large web-application some part of which contains sensetive data and should be secured. I cann't use https entirely due to performance so my suggestion: use http for the unsecure part and https for the secure part. But it seems to be a poor application design to mix http with https from a perspective of maintainability and security. What is the best practices for such a case(some helpful links to articles or books would be very appreciated)?

However, if mixing http/https is acceptable then how can I prevent the next vulnerability:
During a http session a man-in-the-middle changes some piece of html that surreptitiously makes a malicious request directly to https page => the https part of the application actually becomes unsecure due to the html part?

Comment: Is a ssl-offloading firewall an option? i.e. http://www.f5.com/glossary/ssl-offloading.html Then you can build everything without ssl/https

Comment: httpS overhead is relatively minimal these days. CPUs are more than capable of handling it. What kind of overhead are you looking at?

Answer (score 3):

**Enabling SSL (HTTPS) does not mean your application will be secure.**

First, design your application to enable secure scenarios. It seems you don't know much about designing secure apps. In short, *very basically*, you need to accomplish these two things:

- [**authentication**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) of the user before providing access to any secured resource (page),
- [**authorization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) of each request to a secured resource.

Note that, typically, for public-facing web apps server-to-client authentication is covered by SSL (HTTPS; providing the server's certificate which the browser can validate) and client-to-server authentication is covered by some sort of username/password combination, OpenID, etc.

Then, start thinking about how to establish encryption (SSL, very roughly speaking). For low-volume sites SSL implementation if your web server of choice is fine. Fow high-volume sites many hardware-accelerated solutions exist on the market.

Comment: This is an owasp a9 violation.

Comment: @Rook I think the guy is actually lost, missing the point about basic concepts. So argumeting with OWASP is a little bit too heavy artillery here.

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in using HTTPS for only passwords.  If at any point you transmit a session  id that is authenticated or will become authenticated over HTTP then you are in clear violation of [OWASP A9-Insufficient Transport Layer Protection](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9).  Attack tools like [Firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep) can then be used to hijack accounts.

HTTPS is a very light weight protocol,  the most expensive part of the protocol is the handshake which is cached for future transactions with that client.  To have a mixed HTTPS/HTTP application in a secure manner you will have to have a 2nd domain name.  So have your main domain `www.domain.com` as your authenticated one.  Then have a `static.domain.com` for insecure content.  Keep in mind that if you are displaying mixed https/http content on the same page then an attacker can influence the application similar to XSS.  [HTTP-Only Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to prevent the session id from being hijacked. But this is not an ideal solution. If you really care about security you'll use pure HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify the purpose of using different domains, like www.domain.com and www.static.domain.com? http:domain.com and https:domain.com are already initially different by the same origin policy -> why should I use subdomains?

Comment: @Serg  Cookies are issued to a domain. So you can use www.domain.com and only use https on this domain with a cookie.  static.* would be http only and not have a session id.

Comment: It's not clear so far. I want to use htp://domain.com and htps://domain.com. To prevent session hijacking I will use secure cookie. What is the advantage to use static.* in my case?

Comment: Furthermore, I want to use additional token for https pages which do write/delete actions. It prevents hijack https pages by man-in-the-middle through http pages. It's like Cross-Forgery in the context of http and https

Comment: @Serg The first message makes sense to me.  So long as the http cookie isn't authenticated.   The 2nd part of this is totally baffling, i have no idea how this helps.  I would advise against rolling your own session/token.  You should also read the owasp CSRF prevention cheat sheet.

Comment: Yes, I am agreed: The 2nd part of this is totally baffling. Yes, I just mean to prevent from CSRF. Thanks, very much.

Comment: I cann't mark because I have tried to sign up but stackoverflow doesn't have its own login system. I don't know how it's secure to login through Coogle or Facebook -> I don't want to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If using ASP.NET checkout this question: [ASP.NET Security Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295156/asp-net-security-best-practices). It covers security aspects which are relevant outside of ASP.NET such as [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) which is related to the issue regarding HTML tampering.

Overall, if non-secure pages are not expected to receive a lot of traffic then it is simpler to require HTTPS throughout the web application. This way you can have a simple rule which prevents non-HTTPS pages from being opened.

If however you determine performance to be a true concern, it is possible to have a web application utilizing both protocols. Then however you must evaluate all possible security holes. For example, if cookies are used for authentication on secure pages, those cookies must only be sent via HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks. http/example.com and https/example.com are different domains by the same origin policy -> the access is limited from http to https(prevent techniques are likely Cross-Forgery). I know about secure and http-only cookies. Are there other concerns that I should care about when mixing http/https?